# Get view/profile page url from Google Analytics API

Tags: javascript, python, api, google-analytics, google-api

I'm using the Google Analytics Management API to get a list of the user's profiles.  Using the [analytics.management.profiles.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.profiles.list) endpoint I can get a lot of information about a user's profiles, but what I really want is a url to the page they would get if they signed into Google Analytics themselves and clicked on the profile from there.  Is there a way to get this url?  Previously, I was faking it with this url:

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=3#report/visitors-overview/a{ACCOUNT ID}w{WEB PROPERTY ID}p{PROFILE ID}/
```

All the ids in curly braces were numbers that I just happened to notice match up with a profile's account, web property, and profile IDs.

But I soon found that the `authuser=3` part is specific to me; it refers to which of my several Google accounts I am accessing this page through.

So is there a way to generate a url like that which works for anyone who is authenticated and has access to the profile they want to get to?

As a disclaimer, I do not use Google Analytics myself and I don't have anything more than a superficial understanding of it, so please provide links and explain jargon if you can.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to use `authuser=myemail@gmail.com` (or `authuser=myemail@company.com`), using the email address of the account that you want to use to log in, regardless of the order you logged into your multiple accounts.

That is also how I create Gmail/Calendar bookmarks that would always send me to the right inbox:

- https://mail.google.com/mail/u/myname@company.jp/#inbox
- https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/myname@company.jp

I do not know, however, how to create a link to share with other people that'll work for everyone...